# error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'void'

Tags: c, function, compiler-errors

I have seen this error around the web a couple times and yet i have never seen a solution and i just got it.

Error:

```
C:\Users\Jake\Desktop\FightingChance\Fighting_Screen.c:3:1: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'void'
```

Here is the code:

```
#include "main.h"
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void prefight(void)
{
     system("cls");
     printf("%s:\n\nScore = %ld \n\nYour Pre-Fight Stats:\n\nStrength = %ld \nToughness = %ld \nHealth = %d\n\n",name,UserStats[0],UserStats[1],UserStats[2],Userpre_health);
     printf("\n\nEnemy:\n\nYour Enemies Pre-Fight Stats:\n\nStrength = %ld \nToughness = %ld \nHealth = %d\n\n",EnemyStats[1],EnemyStats[2],Enemypre_health);
     printf("\nPress any key to return to menu");
     getch();
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
...
```

I really appreciate the help, if you need any more info or code let me know... thanks in advance!

Comment: What's in main.h

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check your header file main.h. You probably forgot to put a semicolon at the end of whatever is there.

Comment: The only way I know to suggest that is because I've done it myself. :-)

Comment: Thank you I have the same problem in there but I have double spaces in (  ( function